Given invariance of the set of solutions of a differential equation with respect to a Lie group, how do I obtain restrictions on its form?
Suppose I have a differential equation of the form
$$x^{(n)}(t) = F(x^{(n-1)}, x^{(n-2)}, \cdots, x, t)$$
(think of the Newton's equation $\ddot{x} = F(x, \dot{x}, t)$). Suppose I know that the set of solutions of this equation is invariant with respect to a given action of a certain Lie group $G$ on the space to which $x$ belongs (think of a linear or an affine space). This may set certain restrictions on the form of $F$. For instance, we know that the set of solutions of Newton's equation must be invariant with respect to the Galilean group. From this, we can deduce that $F$ does not contain an explicit dependence on $t$, and that $F$ can only depend on differences of coordinates and on relative velocities. The way we prove this is ad hoc, and I wonder if one can, say, from knowing the generators of the Galilean group in a given representation, calculate the restrictions imposed on $F$ using an explicit formula (or at least a general method). I am aware of existence of group analysis of differential equations, but, the way I understand it, it solves the inverse problem, namely, given an equation, to find the symmetry group of its solutions.

You also need to specify an action, not just a Lie group. A Lie group by itself does not determine any symmetries. Newton's equation is not the only equation that has the Galilean group as a symmetry group. More often than not, you don't have symmetries.

Yes, I agree. I also need to specify the action of the group on the space to which $x$ belongs. I have updated the question accordingly.

Regarding the second part of your answer, I don't believe it is relevant to the question I am posing.
